# Does cloudfront support questionsmarks at URLs to fetch a new resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We are porting a website to a AWS cloudfront backed infrastructure which serves static resource from an S3 bucket.

We access the resource like this

```
http://example.com/static/foo.css?hash=1
```

Our CMS generates a new hash when the files changed (cachebusting).

So we upload the file foo.css to the S3  bucket and access

```
http://example.com/static/foo.css?hash=2
```

But still the old contents are displayed. It seems to be cached in cloudfront?

Can this be avoided?

Or does the cms need to be modified?

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure your CloudFront distribution to forward query parameters and use them as part of the cache key. Documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/QueryStringParameters.html).